# Are there any dependencies for nodejs on unix?

Tags: unix, node.js, dependencies

I am planning to release an app based on nodejs. Is there any dependencies that I need to add to my package other than the nodejs executable?
I already did some test on windows and it works with the executable only, but how about on unix systems?
Will it also work?
I'm sorry but I couldn't find this information on the official documentation.

EDIT : I realise I expressed myself wrong, I am sorry about that, so here is exactly what I wanna do :

```
//app.js 
console.log("hello world");

//main.cpp
int main() {
    system("pathtomynode/node.exe app.js");
    return 0;
}
```

On windows, I create a simple.exe with main.cpp, and I put node.exe + app.js + main.exe in an msi and it works fine.

I want to do exactly the same on mac osx with a .pkg, but I want to know if the node binary will be enough, or does the node binary has any dependencies. I managed to do the test on windows beause node installs everything in one folder but I don't know how it goes on mac so that's what I'm asking.

Again I'm sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have here a guide for install node.js on Ubuntu.

http://www.codediesel.com/linux/installing-node-js-on-ubuntu-10-04/

Answer (score 0):

*nix comes in many different flavors and you won't be able to find an executable of node that will run everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

This information is on the wiki page for 'Building and installing Node.js': https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation

Comment: Thanks everyone, but I'm not talking about installing nodejs, I already have... I'm talking about distributing an app that will run locally with a binary version of nodejs.

Comment: I mean I don't want the user to have to get node and compile it himself.

Answer (score 0):

If your package has dependencies on other modules, then you will need to install those using npm (unless your package is also published to npm, in which case it is automatic when your package is npm installed).

Assuming you have your own dependencies and you have specified those dependencies in your package.json file, executing

```
$ npm install
```

...(from the folder that contains your module) will install any dependencies that you have specified.